# How to show title on popup on dialog box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, popup

```
<head>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$("#orderdetail1<?php echo $OrdersRows['ID'];?>").click(function(e){
                          e.preventDefault();   
                          modalbox(this.href,this.title,550,800);
              });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div>   <a id="orderdetail1<?php echo $OrdersRows['ID'];?>" href="<?php echo SITE_ADDRESS."ecommerce/orders/OrderListEdit.php"?>?id=<?php echo $OrdersRows['ID'];?>&Task=configration" title="<?php echo $OrdersRows['CompanyName']." - ".$OrdersRows['FirstName']." ".$OrdersRows['Surname']." - ".$OrdersRows['Phone'];?>"> <img src="../../images/icon_settings.png" border="0" title="<?php echo $OrdersRows['CompanyName']." - ".$OrdersRows['FirstName']." ".$OrdersRows['Surname']."'s Order Detail ";?>"/></a></div>
</body>
```

How to get title using this code. A dialog box is opening using this code but title is not showing

Comment: show us your `modalbox()` function

Comment: If you use jquery ui dialog, just add an attribute title in your div like the example in this link https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: I am using title in achor tag